# News command discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I've made a news command in discord.py using newsapi, I'm having a problem where it sends the top 10 headlines one by one, I wanna make it so that it sends the headline in one embed.
Here's the code :

```py
@commands.command()
    async def news(self, ctx):
      open_bbc_page = requests.get(main_url).json() 
      article = open_bbc_page["articles"] 
      results = []  
      for ar in article: 
          results.append(ar["title"])    
      for i in range(len(results)): 
          ree = (i + 1, results[i])
          em = discord.Embed(title="Here's the trending news", description = f"{ree}",color = 0xa3a3ff)
          await ctx.send(embed=em)[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fel1n.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put them all into the description of the embed like this:

```
for ar in article: 
    results.append(ar["title"])
embeddescription = '/n'.join(results)
em = discord.Embed(title="Here's the trending news", description = embeddescription,color = 0xa3a3ff)
await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Just need to make sure they arent longer than 2048 characters combined, this is the limit for embed descriptions.

Comment: it stills spams it though

Comment: not sure what you mean by that? did you take the `await ctx.send(embed=em)` out of your for loop?

Answer (score 0):

```py
def set_news(ctx, content)
    with open('news.json', 'r') as f:
         msg = json.load(f)

         msg[str("news")] = content

     with open('news.json', 'r') as f:
         json.dump(msg, f)

def check_news()
    with open('news.json', 'r') as f:
         msg = json.load(f)
    return msg

@bot.command()
async def news_set(ctx, content):
      set_news(ctx, content)
      await ctx.send("I set news to {content}!")
      

@bot.command()
async def news(ctx):
      news = check_news()
      await ctx.send(f"News: {news}")
```